# How to make tabbed page back to top using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on this personal project for my one-page profile and can't find the result to what I'm searching for. I'm VERY unfamiliar with JavaScript to begin with and I find these codes on w3schools.

So back to the question, how do I make tabbed page scroll back to top when I visit another tab?

Example (refer JSFiddle below): I scrolled Tab 1 to the bottom, then I visit Tab 2 and when I come back to Tab 1, it is already scrolled back to top.

Plz help :(

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/100hyun/htLe5za1/122/)

```js
function btns(evt, btnName) {
  var i, containerMain, tablinks;
  containerMain = document.getElementsByClassName("containerMain");
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(btnName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Comment: _"I visit Tab 2 and when I come back to Tab 1, it is already scrolled back to top."_ See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: @Rounin I'm sorry, I don't see the correlation to my quesiton?

Comment: I thought you were asking how to make a page scroll back to the top when a visitor has moved their attention to a different tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your JSFiddle, it looks like you meant hidden div elements when you said "tabs"

The `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` control the scrolling position for HTML elements.

Add this code inside your btns function:

```
for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
       containerMain[i].scrollLeft = 0;
       containerMain[i].scrollTop = 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo).

Give it suitable coordinates and call that whenever you switch tabs.

For example at the top of the routine you call when switching tabs do: `window.scrollTo(0,0);`. `window` is the global object in browsers.

Alternatively you could use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), for example on your tabs pane.

Comment: Dumb question: where do I insert this and how does it work in my situation?